# The [user] tag has been burninated!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) is useless. Too ambiguous. Everything we develop is about the *user* of it. What's important for us isn't that there's a user, it's that there's a specific programming question (whose solving should benefit users).

Comment: *but but but... this tag has more then 6000 questions are we sure that we understand the effort to review all of them? or are we just skipping the review and hoping some staff silently remove the tag?*

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thats not a reason to keep it.

Comment: I think we only need to look at the 10 questions with only the user tag and no other tags: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/807927 before we burninate

Comment: What we *really* need is a better pun for that title. We can't work on these conditions!

Comment: @xDaizu It's in phase 2, so a witty title is punallowed.

Comment: @JonClements Should this be advanced to an "official" burnination, since it's been featured for awhile and there seems to be consensus that it should happen?

Comment: I figured the `user` tag was about user-mode as opposed to kernel-mode, but I don't think I've come across many questions using this tag.

Answer (score 139):

I agree that tag should go.

Even if there are people who specialize in [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) I don't think there are experts for [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)s.

I didn't find a question in the list that I thought had a necessity for this tag and thus suggest we just delete it and have it auto-removed from all the questions.

Comment: And the questions that do probably belong on UX.

Comment: @GolezTrol Probably/maybe, but careful not to jump to that conclusion.  There are aspects of UI implementation that deal with coding/design/functionality that are only indirectly related to experience.  If the focus of the question isn't on the experience, don't push for it to be moved because it is disruptive and likely just to get moved back.

Comment: Sure, but in that case, it wouldn't need that tag as well.

Comment: If you ever find an expert on users, let me know. My job could be so much easier if I understood them.

Comment: @Scoots I'm an expert on users! I use a lot of things

Answer (score 20):

Looking at the questions tagged [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user), it seems that the common theme is that they're about user identification, management and/or credentials, not about user interface.  So what tags should be used instead of [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) for those things?

Related tags I can find include [user-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-management) [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) [user-accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-accounts) [user-permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-permissions) [user-registstration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-registstration) [user-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-profile) [userid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userid)... and that's just the ones with `user` in them.

Is [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) useful as a meta-tag for all of these?

Comment: That would be [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication) and [authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization).

Comment: As there is a huge gap between questions between for example user-permission and user-registration I don't see how adding the user tag would make those question better discoverable or limit your results in a useful way.

Comment: Seems reasonable for a blacklist message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=user

Answer (score 12):

Here are the [criteria to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/349538):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   As stated in the question, it's definitely not unambiguous. The tag wiki just states the definition of a user along with a "DO NOT USE!", there is no guidance for when the tag should be used (on the contrary, it says it should not be used).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   I guess it is most of the time, but it's too ambiguous to say anything in the general case.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   Not much. Most programs are made for users, so a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) tag isn't really meaningful just like that. Maybe some questions tagged [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) could benefit from a more specific tag, but [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) is too broad to add any meaningful information.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   As stated in [Chris Dodd's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363575/4284627), a lot questions tagged [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) seem to be about user identification, but there are a lot more specific tags for those. Besides, there are [51 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user+user-interface) tagged [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) and [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), and those questions are about user interface and not user identification, so all [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) questions aren't about the same thing.

So yes, I think that [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) should be burninated.

Answer (score -1):

This website is about how to serve [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)s -- [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)s of programming languages directly, and the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user)s that use their programs indirectly.

They are far from useless.  I think [how to serve <kbd>user</kbd>s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIufLRpJYnI) is key to the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Isn't that the point with (almost) all software? The same would be to add the tag [bug] to a lot of questions.

Comment: +1 and LOL @ all the people who don't get subtle sarcasm (and for that matter, can't click links!)

Comment: If SO tries to do Tron's job, who will do SO's job? (But if we get light cycles, then OK, I'll fight for the users.)

Comment: What did you expect @Blackhawk? we are users D:

Comment: there are no bugs in software...malfeatures, surprises and easter eggs