# Disallow "DO NOT USE" tag wikis in favor of easier blacklisting

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-excerpt

Periodically, there'll be a tag with a tag Wiki saying something like the following (for [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)):

> DO NOT USE: Tag with the library you mean, [api-design], or something else appropriate instead.

There's a burninate request for the tag [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255437/is-there-an-api-to-help-burninate-this-tag) by the way.

Some other examples include [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) ([burnination request here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268187/should-we-burninate-the-user-tag)) and [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) (which probably should have a burnination request).

Predictably, the disclaimers are completely ineffective. [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) has received 10 questions in 18 hours last I checked, and [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) receives an even more discouragingly steady stream of garbage. (Most of the writers of said garbage presumably didn't read the tag description, or, for that matter, the help center).

This is a largely ineffective replacement for blacklisting and burnination. In practice, the burnination system is perpetually backlogged, and blacklisting is hard to get - it can't be done by the community, or even the moderators. Unlike with burnination, there's not really a fixed process for it either.

Can the practice of writing "DO NOT USE" descriptions be banned (preferably in favor of an easier process for burnination and/or blacklisting)? If it needs that tag description, it probably needs burnination and/or blacklisting too.

Comment: The practice should not be banned unless there is a viable alternative already in place. I would love to see a way of allowing a plurality of moderators or CMs to manage the blacklist. Currently I believe it involves a developer...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree - there should be an easier way for the community to participate, too, I think. "DO NOT USE" is a band-aid at best, but the mere existence of the band-aid reflects a part of the system that's currently broken.

Comment: Agreed that it's a band-aid, but since there's zero chance of the situation being improved anytime in the foreseeable future, I would rather have a poor half-solution (that isn't causing other problems) than nothing at all.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, burnination is a slow and laborious process, with good reason.  Yes, there is a backlog of burnination requests, because the number of bad tags *far* outnumber the community's availability to deal with it.

However, in spite of all this, if the "do not use" moniker has prevented at least *one* person from using this tag inappropriately, then I would consider its role fulfilled.

This warning at least slows down the ones who are paying attention.  You'll never slow down the ones who *aren't* paying any attention.