# Old school non-programming books question deleted - why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read/), asked back in the very earliest days of SO (by me), deleted? Granted, it isn't considered a good question anymore, but that's why it was closed and locked. Fair enough. But deletion seems extreme and strikes me as an overall loss for the internet. It's still good content. I for one referred back to it from time to time when thinking about what to read next.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what exactly transpired around Feb 21 to have prompted the deletion on that day without warning... last activity was nearly a year ago.

Comment: Pretty sure that this is related to the user burnination. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268187/the-user-tag-has-been-burninated

Comment: I seem to remember a discussion about it not being maintained effectively or something like that, but I don't remember if that ended in a decision to delete it or not and I can't find the post.

Comment: @DavyM Shot in the dark: Maybe you are thinking about the [definitive C-book listing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/424903)? There was a [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355588/424903) about that one not too long ago that matches what you describe.

Comment: "But deletion seems extreme and strikes me as an overall loss for the internet."  What information do you think is in that post that isn't already readily accessible on the internet?  Do you that that there is information about particular books in that answer that isn't available elsewhere?  Do you think that there aren't good recommendation tools out there for books to read (on the topic of "non-programming books", which means pretty much, "all books" to a close approximation)?  How is that post making the internet a better place?

Comment: Servy, you miss the context. The question is about non-programming books *for programmers*. I.e., If I, as a programmer, want to read something that is *of relevance to my profession* but *isn't specifically about programming*, where do I look? If you think that specific information is available elsewhere, let's see it.

Answer (score 10):

If it were undeleted today, what would it be tagged with?  How could it be tagged in such a way that it would be on-topic, relevant and not described as a meta-tag and thus be subject for burnination?

Problem is, I don't think you can.

This isn't like ["the Definitive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), where the topic and focus is so tight and narrow that it can actually provide value.  You're actually asking for a poll here of books that developers should read and why they should read them.  It's even worse when three of the first four books suggested aren't even programming-related.

Those style of questions don't work here, even if this question was asked from *aeons* ago.  The question's had its time, and now it's time for it to be put to rest.

Comment: That question had been sitting as "untagged" since the burnination of "research" in September. When I went through to clear up the locked "untagged" questions from the "user" tag burnination in February - there was nowhere to actually put it (my arguments being the same as you describe here) - I wasn't going to try and shoehorn an off-topic question into *just anything* - so I removed it and figured I'd see if anyone noticed it (and the other dozen posts I removed) was missing. It'd make a great blog post somewhere for posterity but its time on SO is past...

Comment: It's a shame to lose it from SO because it gets ranked on Google nicely. If moved to a blog post somewhere, it's essentially lost. And how would it fit for format of a blog post with all of the comments? I disagree its time is past. It's useful content. Killing it is a loss for the internet. I don't  think "seeing if anyone would notice" is a good reason to delete. Maybe have an "historic" tag?

Comment: "three of the first four books suggested aren't even programming-related" - that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @CharlesRoper:  Stack Overflow *just* isn't built for content like that.  It just isn't.  Irrespective of the post's age or its hits, this site is still a question and answer site for specific software development problems.  Finding what book to read isn't a specific software development problem.

Comment: @Makoto - In this case, the content fits just fine. Better than any other format I can think of. The combination of Q&A + voting + discussion is great for this sort of content. I agree it's OT for today's SO, but mechanically, the content fits fine. What actual harm does it do to leave it on SO? What harm does it do to delete it? I argue the harm in deleting it is greater. Where else can the content be found?

Comment: @CharlesRoper:  A *simple* Google search will turn up plenty of resources on which books programmers should read.  If you tweak the query you can get a list of non-programming books programmers should read.  Its absence on Stack Overflow isn't going to be sorely missed.

Comment: @Makoto can you give me the exact wording of the simple Google search you're referring to?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_throw_the_baby_out_with_the_bathwater

Comment: "If it were undeleted today, what would it be tagged with?" — why does it need to be tagged to provide value? Some things defy neat categorisation. Doesn't mean we should eliminate those things. By elimintating it, you're implying the content has no value, is misleading or incorrect, or is of poor quality. Having put the straw man of "the content is available elsewhere" argument to bed, I ask again: what actual harm does it do to undelete the question and leave it as an historical piece?

Comment: If it can't be tagged, that's a *strong* indication that it doesn't fit with the existing topics.  I'm really not sure why you're breathlessly trying to win me over here.  I've said my piece.

Comment: @Makoto Beathlessly? Not sure where you're getting that from. I'm asking questions. Whether that "wins you over" or not is beside the point. I asked questions and you appear to be avoiding them. That indicates you have a weak argument to me.

Comment: @CharlesRoper: No; I've made my points, and I don't wish to debate them any further.  You're insisting that we debate them and I don't see a point.  I'm going to busy myself with other things now.