# The [username] tag has been burninated!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I recently encountered [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) and it seems useless to me. It doesn't really add anything to the post.

It currently has 22 people watching it, but I wonder how you could be an expert in usernames or even be interested in following it. It has 1.4k questions but most ones I see are downvoted or at zero. It seems that using [login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/login) instead would be much better in the vast majority of those questions.

---

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It's quite unambiguous but doesn't describe the core problem of the questions which are mostly about login or displaying it somewhere.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It's barely a concept to start with, and the "on-topicness" of it is debatable, compared to password for example.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Well yes.

---

First burnination request here, hope I'm doing it right.

Comment: It is not unlikely that these questioners wanted to tag with [user].  But they can't, that tag was destroyed.  It took three and a half years to get that done, holy cow.  You'd have to wonder what they are going to pummel next when they can't use [username] anymore either.  This tail is wagging the dog.

Comment: *"I wonder how you could be an expert in usernames"*, Actually it's very easy, all you have to do is remember all of the usernames (and profile pictures) you encounter. You'll know you're an expert when you see a user card and think *"Oh, hey! That's the guy that asked that JavaScript question about loose comparisons"*, *"So and so asked about overloading and the C# Attributes.isDefined() function!"* or *"Isn't he the guy that answered the question about `abc` x days ago?"*.

Comment: @kristinalustig There's a special annotation for these post once the burn is completed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384601/you-are-no-longer-required-to-show-your-id?noredirect=1&lq=1 for an example.

Comment: Thanks @Braiam - I marked this as completed and then realized that I didn't know what else I should do to wrap it up. :-) I'm going to get the end part of the process documented internally as soon as I finish it up.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For similar reasons that tag [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user) was [removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268187/the-user-tag-has-been-burninated), the tag [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) is not on-topic for Stack Overflow and should be removed as well.

Alternative existing tags that can be used instead, depending on the context:

- [login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/login), [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication)
- [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) ([burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384601/i-think-id-like-to-burninate-this-tag)), [userid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userid), [identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifier)
- [naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming), [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions)
- [impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/impersonation)

Comment: Really most of these could become [tag:authentication] or [tag:authorization], with maybe a smattering of [tag:delegation] and [tag:impersonation]

Answer (score 6):

[username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Progress:

The [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=username),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Close Vote Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=username) filtered for [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username)
- Searches for questions with [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username):

  - [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Busername%5D+closed%3Ano)
  - [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Busername%5D+closed%3Ayes)
  - [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Busername%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
  - [Without an Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Busername%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=384535)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/username) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.