# You are no longer required to show your [id]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are <s>364</s> about 850 questions with the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag (as of 2020-08-10).  The [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag has the following description:

> ID: Unique attribute in DOM, or any other point of architecture.

"Any other point of architecture"? I'm sensing more than a little ambiguity here.

The expanded information is:

> The id property sets or returns the id of an element (the value of an element's id attribute).
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp

One of my software engineering professors in undergrad used to tell us that you shouldn't have to use the word `and` when describing what a method or class does - if you find that you do, you probably need to refactor. By the same token, you shouldn't have to the word `or` when describing what a tag should be used for. (You'll note that this description does, in fact, use the word "or"). This tag has numerous different meanings; it does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts.

One of the top answerers has given 4 answers; every other top answerer has given just 1 answer.  One of the top askers has asked 2 questions; less surprisingly, every other top asker has only asked 1 question.  The tag was created at the end of May 2018.

Given the ambiguity of this tag, it adds nothing useful to the posts and can be eliminated without harm. Can we burninate it?

Comment: Why not simply a synonym of [tag:identifier]?

Comment: @Cœur I'm not convinced that it applies to all of the questions, though - for example, some of them are asking about some kind of `id` tag or attribute (e.g. in HTML or XML), which isn't exactly the same thing as [identifier].

Comment: Uhm to a certain merit. While `id` is a tag in HTML/XHTML, it is in fact an identifier in the technical sense

Comment: Regardless, I do agree the tag should be burninated. It's way too ambiguous and there are more specific and descriptive tags out there (eg. `userid`, `login`and in general there's rarely in issue in HTML where you'd need to specifically tag for `id`)

Comment: `id` does not per se means identifier. In (mainly) functional languages `id` typically means the "identity" function (a function mapping something to itself), and in Python `id` is used to obtain a "signature" that is unique per object. So the tag also has a lot of meanings (and likely a lot of questions are mistagged).

Comment: I think it should be more specific: `html-id` (`id="…"` attribute), `android-id` (View id – `android:id="…"` attribute, …

Comment: @jiwopene So, we need a tag for each property that a element of html can have? Of course not. Tagging with [html] should be enough for anyone to know that some knowledge on html is needed.

Comment: I think this should be synonymized with [tag:identifier] as Cœur suggested in a comment.

Comment: @TylerH That wouldn't make sense for Python. [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is a function that gets an object's identity, while [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) are names. (I assume this also applies to other languages, but I only know Python.) Removing [tag:id] would be fine though since there's already an [tag:identity] tag.

Comment: @wjandrea Python would get something like [tag:python-id] then. Or we can replace the ID tag on Python questions with the identity tag. Or some other process.

Comment: @TylerH Because [identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier_(computer_languages)) is not the same as [unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier), and "id" typically refers to the latter. The fact this suggestion was even made demonstrates the ambiguity of the tag.

Comment: Burn it. There are way too many tags that became useless by being overused, this is one of them.

Comment: @jpmc26 ID is short for Identity, Identifier, Identification Document, etc. A "unique identifier" is redundant.

Comment: @TylerH Not true. In a programming language, I can have two variables named `value` in different scopes, even overlapping scopes. `value` is still an identifier. In a database, I have can two tables named `mytable` in separate schemas. `mytable` is, by itself and without qualification, an identifier regardless. "Identifier" in programming usually refers to a specific semantic type belonging to a *lexical* element of code. As a term, it does not usually refer to a piece of data that uniquely identifies related data like "ID" does.

Comment: @jpmc26 Both links you pointed to on Wikipedia describe a unique object. If some programming languages interpret them wrong, that's on those languages, and we'll need a <lang>-id tag for that language. For most folks, "ID" means "unique".

Comment: @Cœur, the [identify] tag should also burn along with [id].

Comment: @TylerH You are making up things. The only mention of uniqueness in the first article I linked is a pair of off hand notes about particular languages having uniqueness rules and HTML `id` attributes requiring uniqueness. (The latter doesn't even really belong in the article, since those aren't identifiers in the computer science sense.) And I literally provided you with examples of how the identifiers need not be unique. Every modern mainstream programming language has a concept of scope, meaning every modern language allows for non-unique identifiers. There's nothing "wrong" about that.

Comment: Where are we supposed to ask questions about the [id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego)?

Comment: I thought the key question is "Does it make sense to be known as an expert of `[id]`?" No -> Burninate.

Comment: @MooingDuck No, [the burnination criteria is a *lot* more extensive than that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071). That's not even an especially good heuristic or simplification.

Comment: @MooingDuck The burn criteria are no longer focused on whether the tag actually has any value. The criteria are now tailored to minimize the number of tags that qualify because it's so arduous and time consuming and slow to perform a burn. You'd think that would lead to pushes for a more efficient process, but no, nobody cares about that. In introducing the new criteria, the burn process has become even slower and more arduous, exacerbating the problem and wasting even more time.

Comment: @jpmc26: The burn criteria are still the same [as they were in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/239191/1). I don't understand what you're talking about here.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Those criteria weren't effectively adopted until the burn process became more strict, which didn't happen until [a couple of years later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/324071/1).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image: Trogdor]

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Remove [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) from questions referring to the [HTML id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)
- Replace [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) with [primary-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primary-key) for questions about the primary key of a database
- Remove [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) from questions referring to the [Python builtin function "id"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)
- Generally, for all other questions with the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag, try to vote to close if the question is off-topic. If a question is on-topic and can be edited, please remove the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag while doing so.

## Progress:

The [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=id),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bid%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bid%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bid%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bid%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219930/burnination-progress-for-the-id-tag)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=384601)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 100):

Yes, burninate the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag.

The ambiguity is too great. A tag should be descriptive for one specific thing only, but that isn't the case here. It doesn't add anything to a post which is tagged with it.

IMHO, the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag fails Question 1., 3. and 4. of the [tag burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/12139179) for sure. Answer to Question 2 whether the concept behind is on-topic to the site is controversial, but as said "*in any case, the ultimate criterion for burnination is whether the tag is actually causing harm: ...*" I think it adds harm as it brings only confusion to the site, which is not constructive for anyone.

Comment: Question 2 is hard to answer if the tag itself is ambiguous - "What exact concept do you mean?" is the only sane response to that question then.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yeah, the [original guidance only needed one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575). If it fail the first one there's a good chance that answering later questions is straight no and or maybe.

Comment: Technically, if a tag is ambiguous, but on-topic, it calls for [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation] rather than a burnination. However, in this case, there wouldn't be any questions left post disambiguation, and therefore is similar to a burnination.

Comment: if it fails 1,3 & 4 in what sense can it be on topic only in the meta sense that its on topic for burnination..

Comment: @BhargavRao, add `[identify]` to the black list while you're at it.

Answer (score 40):

As mentioned by most others, [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) needs to be burninated. I went through the list of questions, as well as the related tags for [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) and had some observations:

- The tag wiki for the [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag talks about the usage of [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) for [the HTML id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). This is a valid reason, and would require its own unambiguous tag. I would suggest [html-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-id), as it is in line with the other similar attribute/element tags, like [html-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table), [html-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-input) and so on.
- The next most frequent usage of [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) is about the [Python builtin function "`id`"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). Here's where I'm a bit unsure as to what would be the better tag. I'm not much a fan of creating a [python-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-id), as it would be very specific and hard to find. I'd go with either removing the tag or using [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identity) here, as the very definition of the function is to *Return the “identity” of an object*.
- The posts tagged with [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) seem to be a lot about ids in general, and the tag can just be removed from them. I did find a few low-quality questions in this group. The same was the situation with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), as well, where a lot of questions were about grouping on an "id" column. The tag isn't relevant in these cases.
- Finally in the cases where it is used to represent the primary key of a database, the [primary-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primary-key) would be the better tag instead of the ambiguous [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/id) tag.

Comment: We don't need [tag:html-id]. We can use have a [tag:html-attribute] tag or something if there isn't one that covers all HTML tag attributes, if we need one. In fact, there *was* a [tag:html-attributes] but it was synonymized to [tag:html].

Comment: I am with TylerH on this one. Table and Input are HTML elements, but ID is an attribute of any element. We don't need such granularity.

Comment: Sure, @TylerH, I don't mind either way.

Comment: That's the thing Bhargav, your word has weight. If you don't care either way, don't put your weight behind these "solutions" that just create more tags for the sake of it. [Tags have a purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198024/can-we-start-cleaning-up-table-tag-and-burninate-it-asap#comment627607_198024) and if that purpose wouldn't be advanced by the operations we do with tags, then why should we do anything with them?

Comment: BTW, we already said that HMLT tags don't require their own tags. Every burnination about a html element that can't survive outside of the html specification (svg, for example) made that abundantly clear.

Comment: if `id` is kept, it would be an argument to add virtually every function or language construct form whatever language to the set of tags.

Comment: Regarding the proposal to have [tag:html-id] --> 
[Should we get rid of the \[div\] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253554/1595451) Nowadays [tag:div] is a synonym of [tag:html]. I vote for having [tag:html-attribute] and if [tag:html-id] appears, make it a synonym of it.

Answer (score -19):

Alternate proposal: merge with [identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifier), as suggested by [Cœur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur) in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384601/i-think-id-like-to-burninate-this-tag/400158#comment693716_384601)

I'm strongly opposed to this cause it wouldn't make sense for Python. [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is a function that gets an object's identity, while [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) are names. I assume this also applies to other languages, but I only know Python.

Comment: I'm opposed because [identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier_(computer_languages)) refers to a name that the programmer uses in code (including SQL code or similar languages). "id" typically refers to a [unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier). Those are *totally* different.

Comment: Alternate proposal: burninate [tag:identifier] too

Comment: @Joundill Hey now, I just self-answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62865301/4518341) about identifiers ;) I'm also starting a project about identifiers, so [the top questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifier%20python?sort=MostFrequent&edited=true) should be useful.

Comment: @wjandrea To be fair, the identifier being discussed in those questions is different depending on the context. There are a decent number of questions in there relating to `id` in the HTML DOM, which is technically not incorrect.

Comment: In first paragraph you say merge, in second you are against. So what are you up to? I downvoted the answer just in case..

Comment: @Sinatr it's moving the proposal from comments.

Comment: In case the inference is lost, let me copy my comment from the question: So, we need a tag for each property that a programming language can have? Of course not. Tagging with [python] should be enough for anyone to know that some knowledge on python is needed.

Answer (score -26):

Alternate proposal: merge with [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identity)

I don't have a strong opinion on this myself, but FWIW it would make sense for Python. The [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function gets an object's identity.

Comment: I disagree. The `id` function literally gets an object's id, not identity. Plus, this tag is not only for python.

Comment: @10Rep But "ID" stands for "identity"... And I realize it's not only for Python, that's why I said "FWIW".

Comment: Why have you posted two almost identical proposals? [The other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400160/7395911).

Comment: @Bernardo So people can vote on them. People were leaving suggestions as comments on the question, but you can't downvote comments, only upvote. And they're not almost identical; I'm talking about two different tags and I have two different opinions.

Comment: @wjandrea Sorry, my mistake I misread the tag XD