# Completed burninate request post notice still uses old name of tag blocking feature

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, post-notice

Earlier this month, the feature previously known as *blacklisted tags* [was renamed by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352702/377214) to [*blocked tags*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag).

However, the "Completed Burninate Request" post notice (which seems to only exist on Meta Stack Overflow) still refers to it under the old name of "blacklisted" tags.

Example post notice on [You are no longer required to show your [id]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384601):

> This tag has been **burninated!** If you notice it re-appearing with some frequency, please [propose that it be blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests/239192#239192).

That last part of the sentence should be changed to "propose that it be blocked" (or "propose that it be blocked from creation").

Additionally, the title of the Meta.SE question that is linked in the notice has been changed, but the link still has the old title in the URL slug: it links to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-tag-blacklist-requests/239192#239192`. That should be changed to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-requests-to-block-tags/239192#239192` (or use one of the short forms that doesn't hardcode a title into the URL).

Comment: I personally don't think the URL itself is enough of an issue to need any attention. The post verbiage should definitely be changed though.

Comment: @zcoop98 why not change the URL at the same time? New URL still works, takes 2 seconds to do.

Comment: @10Rep Can we please stop doing these pointless edits? Those needlessly bump the question on the main page. If you're editing something, then make sure that your edits have some value in them, rather than just highlighting a sentence that was already highlighted (in italics).

Comment: @BhargavRao Sure, but can I add the [tag:tag-blacklist] tag back?

Comment: @10Rep I explicitly left out that tag because this isn't about the tag blocking feature, but about the post notice.

Comment: Perhaps [meta-tag:burninate-system] would be more appropriate?

Comment: @RyanM No, burnination is a separate feature.

Comment: It is, but this is the post notice used as part of the burnination system.  It's ultimately up to you, of course: it's your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed. The updated notice now says

> This tag has been **burninated!** If you notice it re-appearing with some frequency, please [propose that it be blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/how-should-we-make-requests-to-block-tags/239192#239192).

Thanks for the report!