# We need more nominations for "Featured on Meta"

Tags: discussion, meta, sidebar, community-bulletin, featured-questions

### Think a question on Meta should be tagged [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and appear in the sidebar under the "Featured on Meta" section?

Post an answer here to nominate a question! Be sure to *include a link* to the question in your answer, along with a *brief justification* of why you think it should be featured.

#### What type of posts are allowed/not allowed to be featured?

Featured questions should be of broad, general interest to the entire community of Stack Overflow users. For general guidelines on what can, or should not be featured, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387626

#### Why do we need to organize it in this fashion?

Having individual users raise flags on questions to nominate them for featured status doesn't work well:

- It doesn't scale
- It isn't sufficiently visible to the community
- It doesn't allow for a backlog

#### Proposed Workflow for featuring requested posts

Moderators will periodically review answers to this question, and [decide whether to feature your suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator). Among other factors, this decision will be based on:

- Moderators' judgment and your [given rationale for featuring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387626)
- The number and nature of the questions that are currently featured
- Community consensus, as measured by votes and/or comments on the nominations

Once a question has been featured, its corresponding nomination post will be deleted. (*This does allow for re-nominations, but please think *very* carefully about that!*) Pending nominations that have not yet been acted upon will remain visible.

Moderators retain the rights to summarily delete nominations they feel are inappropriate and to feature questions that have *not* been nominated here.

#### History of previously-featured questions

Use this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1254512/meta-stack-overflow-featured-history) to view the previously-featured Meta posts.

---

[Sort the answers below by active](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390794/nominations-for-featured-on-meta-questions?answertab=active#answers) to see the latest request first.

Comment: Sort of feels like this would desirably be a UI thing, with a button under posts next to the "shared", "edit", "close", "flag" links -- a "vote to feature this".  Otherwise, it would be easy to not know this question exists.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm afraid this question here will become mess over time. Is there a plan on how to deal with either accepted or "outdated" nominations? 10k Users would see many deleted answers then.

Comment: I can neither build nor roll out UI things, @Conspicuous. However, I can do this. Also...while I’m sympathetic to the visibility concerns regarding this, and still thinking of relatively unobtrusive ways of increasing its visibility, I don’t think that nominating a Meta question to be featured is nearly common enough to be a first-class link under the question. It’s going to be something used primarily by Meta regulars and veteran users, but I’m not overly concerned about that, since these are the folks in the best position to decide what should be featured.

Comment: Yes, @Tom: delete ‘em! 10k+ users will see lots of deleted answers, but so what? They’ll be sorted at the end, visible if you want to go spelunking, but otherwise out of the way. Note that abuses of the Q&A system like this are not unprecedented. Consider the formatting sandbox, the community open-source ads nominations, etc. The Q&A engine shouldn’t have an issue with a large number of deleted answers. If it does, we’ll cross that bridge when we come to it. (Maybe delete the question itself and start fresh.)

Comment: How are <10k users supposed to know if they're repeating something that was already suggested, but got deleted? Would it make sense to keep a list of suggestions (perhaps in the question in a snippet)? Fortunately you can check a single question's revision history for the featured tag, but that doesn't help you if you wanted to know about similar questions.

Comment: @Laurel I think you (along with several of the others) are over-thinking this... Yeah, users with < 10k aren't going to be able to see deleted answers, so there's a marginal risk that they might nominate something that has already been featured and/or something that had already been declined. That's not really a big issue. No one is going to be punished for making an unpopular suggestion, or even one that is removed by a moderator. This is Meta: reputation doesn't matter, downvotes are free, literally all we do is express our opinion.

Answer (score 12):

It's been quite awhile since we've featured any burnination requests, so I'd like to suggest that we feature some of them. I've highlighted a few of the [highest-voted outstanding requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bburninate-request%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20score%3a20) that identify a single tag below:

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [I think [I'd] like to burninate this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384601/i-think-id-like-to-burninate-this-tag) - not that I'm biased or anything :)
2. [Wrong [username]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384535/wrong-username) - kinda a meta tag
3. [Burninate request: [amazon] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345643/burninate-request-amazon-tag) - since we got rid of a lot of other company names already. Plus, I've gotta love tags with "DO NOT USE" tag usage guidance that people continue to use anyway.

There are a bunch more to choose from too.

Comment: I would also like to see burnination and tag clean up requests featured every so often. It seems like many of them don't happen just because they don't get views. (I may be biased, having just made a request.) That may be more feasible once there are more moderators or current moderators are less busy.

Comment: This would require participation from mods; the normal burnination mod, Bhargav, is inactive.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate ["How do I ask a good question" page needs explicit statement "Don't repost your questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400273/839601)

Reason for nomination: in the absense of Help Center guidance on this important point, having this prominently visible on sidebar is next best thing we can do to educate inexperienced askers and prevent unnecessary load on content curators, and decrease frustration of both mentioned groups.

Comment: having it temporarily displayed in the featured list is hardly a solution to the problem... instead i'd say this should be featured because it's a discussion/feature request that hopes to improve upon that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I nominate [People should get notified when answers to their questions are edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306419/6574038) to get featured on meta.

The feature request is still of interest for the community, since it is highly upvoted and has already received solution proposals in four committed answers.

However, probably because there was no official reaction so far, the discussion seems to become orphaned. It should therefore be featured on meta to regain the original attention.

Comment: I'm humbled that you think a response by a moderator would be in any way "official", much less that it might prevent a proposal from becoming orphaned. But, unfortunately, it doesn't really work that way.

Comment: @CodyGray You're absolutely right, "no official reaction" should suffice (edited) .